# How to set up PointCloud SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, unity-game-engine, point-clouds

I downloaded the PointCloud Unity Plugin [here](http://developer.pointcloud.io/sdk/download).  I then followed all the directions on the README file exactly.  To be clear, I created a new Unity 4 project, set the platform to iOS in the build settings, set a Bundle Identifier for my app in the player settings, imported the PointCloudUnityPlugin custom package, used the PointCloud menu to request and set an Application Key, opened the test scene and then clicked build and run.  When it built, I got an error message in Unity saying "UnityException: Launching iOS Project via XCode4 failed.  Check editor log for details."  Then, when the project opens in the the Beta version of Xcode 5 (because for no apparent reason it doesn't work in Xcode 4), the Unity splashscreen comes up and then the screen just becomes blue for no apparent reason.  It remains blue and there appears to be nothing I can do (rather than doing some cool augmented reality with a dominoe like it;s supposed to do).  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you have to install both the Unity plugin and the sample iOS project and they work together.  I'm not sure why but it is working fine now that I have done that.

Comment: What do you mean by install both? Can you explain further?

Comment: Ok, it's been a while since I worked on this but to the best of my recollection there were assets in the sample project which would generally be considered "SDK" in that they were necessary in order to compile projects.  So I had to "install" (bad word for this sorry) the sample project in that I had to include it as a scene within my Unity project after downloading it from the Asset Store.  I'm sorry for the unclear response and long wait time :/